# How to properly overflow 2D coordinates on an overflowing/circular map?

Tags: 2d, mathematics, javascript, algorithm

I made a simple Snake game designed for trying Snake bots. I thought the base map functions work, but now I found there is an error. What I need is to properly translate any coordinates outside the actual map to coordinates within it.

For example, if you're at the right edge of a 10x10 map and you go to (zero-indexed) [10, 5], you'd expect to pop out at [0, 5]. That works in my implementation, but not the negative overflow. I tried a lot of formulas in the dev console and just can't figure it out. Consider this code:

```
    /**
     * Normalizes overflow of a point so that it is within the map
     * @param {number|Vector2} x
     * @param {number} y
     * @returns {Vector2}
     */
    normalizePoint(x, y) {
        if (x instanceof Vector2) {
            y = x.y;
            x = x.x;
        }

        // auto overflow
        if (x >= this.size) {
            x = (x % this.size);
        }
        else if (x < 0) {
            // ???
        }
        if (y >= this.size) {
            y = (y % this.size);
        }
        else if (y < 0) {
            // one of the formulae I tried, does not work for all values
            y = this.size + (y-1) % this.size;
        }
        return new Vector2(x, y);
    }
```

`Vector2` is a simple object with properties `x` and `y`. `this.size` represents the map size. For negative coordinates, I am not getting the correct results. I want overflowing X and Y coords to resolve to the same numbers. For example for a 5x5 map, all rows should be equal X coords after normalizing:

| Real map coord X: | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Negative alternatives: | -5 | -4 | -3 | -2 | -1 |
| Negative alternatives: | -10 | -9 | -8 | -7 | -6 |

I would prefer it to be a O(1) formula, rather than some weird loop. With a loop, I solved it like this:

````
if (x < 0) {
            while (x < 0) {
                x += this.size;
            }
        }

```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to wrap just a few steps out of bounds (up to negative `size`), then you can do this like so:

```
(size + coordinate) % size
```

When `coordinate = -1` then this gives you `(size - 1) % size = size - 1`.

And when `coordinate = size` then this gives you `(size + size) % size = 0`.

For any value in between (`0` to `size - 1`), this behaves the same as the identity function, giving you `coordinate` back unchanged.

So you can safely use this one formula for all cases, with no `if` branching required to change behaviour depending on whether you're overflowing, underflowing, or in-range.

---

If you need to wrap further than negative size, you can increase the multiple of `size` you add inside the parentheses:

```
(3 * size + coordinate) % size
```

This will wrap correctly from `-3 * size` up to the maximum representable integer, and you can keep growing that coefficient if you need.

---

If you have no bound on how far your coordinates can go in the negative direction, then you can do it with a double modulo:

```
((coordinate % size) + size) % size
```

The inner modulo brings us into the range of `-(size-1)` to `(size -1)` and then we apply the original formula around it to bring us to `0` to `size - 1`.

---

Just to note, this is not circular wrapping, but toroidal. Your map area remains a rectangle, not a circle.

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome, now I also do not have to copy the point object to avoid messy code since I can normalize the coordinates with this one liner.

Comment: I found out that this solution does not work properly. For size 10 and coordinate -11, you get -1, instead of 9.

Comment: It works exactly properly in the range I described. If you need to go further into the negatives, you modify it as shown above.